# ASA is not forwarding packets to egress interface

Tags: port-forwarding, cisco-asa, sip

We are seeing some very strange behaviour from our Cisco ASA 5505 running `9.1(2)`

We have a SIP PBX inside our network. It's got a bit of an odd configuration, it listens for inbound SIP requests for our trunk on `UDP/60052`.

So in our ASA, I have a Port Forwarding from `UDP/5060` to `UDP/65002` on our outside interface. 90% of this time, this works just fine.

However, the remaining 10% of the time, and so far it appears to be randomly, the ASA decides not to do *anything* with the incoming `UDP/5060` traffic. A packet capture on the ASA shows the SIP `INVITE` request hitting the `outside` interface, but it never reaches the egress interface.

We are not using any SIP inspection, as the internal server uses `STUN` to remap its SIP headers.

NAT Rule:

```
nat (outside,any) source static obj_any obj_any destination static interface Swyx service Swyx-5060-Service-UDP Swyx-SIP-65002-UDP no-proxy-arp description BC Swyx 5060 > 65002
```

ACL:

```
object-group service DM_INLINE_SERVICE_3
 service-object object Swyx-RTP-55000
 service-object object Swyx-SIP-65002-UDP
 service-object object RTP

access-list outside_access_in_1 extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_SERVICE_3 any object Swyx log critical
```

What have I missed? Is there any known bugs in this version of the ASA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, not entirely helpful here, but we have replaced that ASA with a Mikrotik router and this issue has gone away.

It's clearly some sort of bug or issue with the Cisco ASA, but I've basically got fed up with these small ASA's and started replacing them.

Answer (score 0):

Can you validate the cpu usage and mem usage of the asa when that happen ? Its easy to make a asa drop packets on high load with big WAN link

Comment: Good point. I do not keep a history of the CPU usage. It's only a 20Mbps link though, so it's unlikely to be saturating the CPU.

Comment: @MarkHenderson You are right at 20mbps it should work good, let us know the result if you can rule that out. The fact it's only at 10% of time is strange, thus the ACL is ok. Can it be some remote devices that send malformed packet ? (firmware update needed for thoses?)